# QTcpSocket becomes invalid

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to write a class for communication with a microwave generator using SCPI. Here its header file:

```
<!-- language: c++ -->
#ifndef GENERATOR_H
#define GENERATOR_H

#include <QTcpSocket>

class generator
{
public:
    generator(QString IP_port, unsigned int scpitimeout);
   ~generator();

    bool connectToGen();
    bool resetgen();
    QString getIDN();
    bool setFreq(double freq);
    bool setPow(double pow);
    bool ALCoff();
    bool setPW(double pw);
    bool setPRI(double pri);
    bool activatePmod();
    bool activateRFpow();
    bool deactivateRFpow();
    QString getlasterror();

private:
    QString genIP;
    QString IDstring;
    QString lasterror;
    unsigned int genPort;
    unsigned int timeout;

    // TCP/IP socket
    QTcpSocket *socket = nullptr;

    bool sendCommand(QString command);
    QString sendQuery(QString query);
};

#endif // GENERATOR_H
```

Most public functions in class just call sendCommand() or sendQuery() with different parameters. For example:

```
<!-- language: c++ -->
bool generator::activatePmod()
{
    if ( sendCommand(":PULM:STAT ON;\n") )
        return true;
    lasterror = "Some error text here.";
    return false;
}

QString generator::getIDN()
{
    return sendQuery("*IDN?;\n");
}
```

I work with this class in the following way. I call the class constructor from another function, by creating class object. Then I call connectToGen() function. It creates TCP/IP-socket and opens it. After this, I call some public functions from class several times. Here are the mentioned functions:

```
<!-- language: c++ -->
generator::generator(QString IP_port, unsigned int scpitimeout)
{
    QStringList ipportlist = IP_port.split(QRegExp("(:)"));
    genIP = ipportlist.at(0);
    genPort = ipportlist.at(1).toUInt();
    timeout = scpitimeout;
}

bool generator::connectToGen()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(NULL);
    socket->connectToHost(genIP,genPort);
    if (!socket->waitForConnected(timeout)) {
        lasterror = "Some error.";
        return false;
}

bool generator::sendCommand(QString command)
{
    bool x1 = socket->isValid();
    bool x2 = socket->isWritable();
    socket->write(command.toLocal8Bit());
    if (!socket->waitForBytesWritten(timeout))
        return "";
    if (sendQuery("*OPC?;\n").toInt() != 1)
        return false;
   return true;
}

QString generator::sendQuery(QString query)
{
    socket->write(query.toLocal8Bit());
    if (!socket->waitForBytesWritten(timeout))
        return "";
    if (!socket->waitForReadyRead(timeout))
        return "";
   return QString(socket->readAll());
}
```

The problem is that after several functions calls socket becomes invalid. Variable x1 becomes false. If I try to execute isWritable() or write(), segmentation fault occurs.
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I figured out what the problem was. I passed the generator object into a function without reference and initialized the connection from this function. So when the function was executed, the copy of the object was just deleted, and the socket was deleted with it. Then I tried to send the command using the initial generator object, which, of course, did not contain any sockets. So all of it was completely my fault.

Comment: can you try "socket ->setSocketOption(QAbstractSocket::KeepAliveOption, 1);" after you created the "socket" ? see if that helps.  PS:you seem to be missing "}" after "return false;" in "connectToGen()" function. cheers

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it tomorrow and notify you about results. I've missed "}" while preparing my code in Notepad++ for this question. This mistake is not from actual code.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I passed the generator object into a function without reference and initialized the connection from this function. So when the function was executed, the copy of the object was just deleted, and the socket was deleted with it. Then I tried to send the command using the initial generator object, which, of course, did not contain any sockets. So all of it was completely my fault.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved it. Please update your original post to reflect this so it may be of help to others.

Comment: Done. Thank you for help!